# Ignore X-Frame headers on IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, http-headers

On google chrome I am able to ignore X-Frame headers by installing this plug in:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe/related

**In other words I can place all the websites that I use the most on one site using an iFrame** some of the websites only work on IE.

How can I do the same on IE?  Maybe there is a place I can change on internet options?

### P.S.

I know I can use fiddler. But I do not want to run fiddler all the time. Is there a plugin just like the chrome one?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it is possible to ignore X-Frame-Options heads within IE. You could use a headless proxy like https://github.com/iSECPartners/tcpprox or https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy to strip all of the X-Frame-Options headers before the requests reach your browser. However, this isn't a good idea because you're purposefully making yourself vulnerable to UI redress attacks.